# Load vue routes in a component instead of app.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using **Laravel** and currently, I'm loading my **Vue** routes in `apps.js` like this:

```
import MyComponentMain from './components/MyComponentMain.vue';

import MyComponentOne from './components/MyComponentOne.vue';
import MyComponentTwo from './components/MyComponentTwo.vue';

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/my-component-main',
        component: MyComponentMain
    },
    {
        path: '/my-component-one',
        component: MyComponentOne
    },
    {
        path: '/my-component-two',
        component: MyComponentTwo
    },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: router
});
```

How can I move the declarations of `MyComponentOne` and `MyComponentTwo` routes to `MyComponentMain.vue` ?

`./components/MyComponentMain.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <router-link
      class="nav-link"
      to="/my-component-one"
    >
    <router-link
      class="nav-link"
      to="/my-component-two"
    >
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  mounted () {
    console.log('Main component mounted.');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It's not clear _why_ you want to do this. Importing the components into your router definition is pretty standard so why change from the norm?

Comment: @Phil That's because these routes are only used in this main component and I have many other routes like these which take too much lines in my `app.js` bundle file, I'd like to clean it and only load necessary routes.

Comment: Routes must all be defined up-front. You can't lazy-load route definitions

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you can split the routes by creating a *routes* folder and organise your routes by file and merge in `app.js`, similar to how you would do vue store modules.

**/routes/MyComponentMain.vue**

```
import MyComponentMain from './components/MyComponentMain.vue';

const componetMainRoutes = [

    {
        path: '/my-component-main',
        component: MyComponentMain
    },
];

export componetMainRoutes
```

**/routes/MyComponentOne.vue**

```
import MyComponentOne from './components/MyComponentOne.vue';

const componetOneRoutes = [

    {
        path: '/my-component-one',
        component: MyComponentOne
    },
];

export componetOneRoutes
```

**/routes/MyComponentTwo.vue**

```
import MyComponentTwo from './components/MyComponentTwo.vue';

const componnetTwoRoutes = [

    {
        path: '/my-component-two',
        component: MyComponentTwo
    },
];

export componnetTwoRoutes
```

and then bring them all together in `app.js`

```
import componetMainRoutes from "./routes/componetMainRoutes"
import componetOneRoutes from "./routes/MyComponentOne"
import componnetTwoRoutes from "./routes/componnetTwoRoutes"

const routes = [
  ...componetMainRoutes,
  ...componetOneRoutes,
  ...componnetTwoRoutes
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: router
});
```